# firefox os download failed install application

Tags: firefox-os

When I try to test installing my app in the Firefox OS simulator and phone I get "Download stopped" error and the application does not get installed even though the application successfully passes the Firefox validator.

See package manifest.

```
{
    "name": "FriendFinder GPS",
    "package_path" : "http://wormholesoft.com/ffos/FriendFinder/FriendFinder.zip",
    "version": "1",
    "developer": {
        "name": "NAME",
        "url": "http://Wormholesoft.com/ffos/FriendFinder/FriendFinder"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded your zip from http://wormholesoft.com/ffos/FriendFinder/FriendFinder.zip, unzipped it and removed `"type": "certified"` from the manifest, as you don't need it for the permissions you currently ask for (geolocation). See the [app permissions docs at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/App_permissions) to find out what app types support what permissions and also see about the [app types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Publishing/Packaged_apps#Types_of_packaged_apps). Then I selected the folder from App Manager to install it as a packaged app and tested it with the simulator and it seems to work fine (I get the login screen).

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a cache manifest error: http://ngokevin.com/blog/fxos-cache/